# Outlook 2010 and ActiveSync (Z-Push)

Tags: exchange, outlook

I would like to sync contacts and calendars with Outlook 2010 using the Z-Push activesync implementation and caldav/carddav/imap.

Does Outlook 2010 actually support ActiveSync or how does it connect with exchange-servers?

Answer (score 4):

No version of Outlook supports ActiveSync to your own Exchange Server. Outlook 2013 has ActiveSync support but [it is not supported for connecting to your Exchange Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631135.aspx#BKMK_EXActiveSync), only "outlook.com".

Comment: What protocol does Outlook use to connect to Exchange then? Are there any alternatives for it like Z-Push for ActiveSync?

Comment: Outlook talks to Exchange through a Remote Procedure Call (RPC) protocol using the Messaging Application Programmer Interface (MAPI). On private networks the RPC is typically done directly over TCP (port 135). To communicate with an Exchange Server computer across the Internet via MAPI Microsoft recommends "Outlook Anywhere", which tunnels the RPC over HTTPS.